# Pass different data members in function in C

Tags: c, function, struct, parameters

Just a question about programming in C, as I'm new to it.

So I have a `typedef struct` called `students`, and I've created an array of them. Each of them has data members of `q1`, `q2`, `q3`, `q4`, `final`.

I'm trying to do calculations on each of those data members and currently i have separate functions for each like so:

```
int highestQ1(student[], int);
int highestQ2(student[], int);
int highestQ3(student[], int);
int highestQ4(student[], int);
int highestFinal(student[], int);
int highestQ1(student[], int);
```

But this makes the code really long, and I'm wondering if there's a way for me to create a function that will allow me to specify which data member of the structure to use for calculation as the parameter, that way I can just use one function and lean out my code.

An example of my goal would be

```
int highestVal(student[] data, int size, char[] wildcard)
{
    int i = data[x].wildcard;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Almost all your functions have `Q` and a number in common. So, you could just have one function with three arguments: a `student[]` value, an `int` value and a `Q` value or `Final` value. For example `int highestQ1(student[], int, char[]);` should do. The third argument could be `"Q1"` or `"Q2"` or `"Q3"` or `"Q4"` or `"Final"`.

Comment: What you have written is  not possible in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use offset as pointer on data member:

```
void print(const student* students, int size, int offset)
{
    for (int i = 0; i != size; ++i) {
        const int member = *((const int*)(((const char*) &students[i]) + offset));

        printf("%d ", member);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

with call similar to:

```
print(students, size, offsetof(student, q1));
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/up4LB3)

Comment: Wasn't it what I proposed?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: Yes, Proposed mostly at the same time. upvoted your solution Btw.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you wanted to find the highest mark from an array of students given a wildcard/group value, the following comes pretty close to answering your question:

```
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct student {
    char * name;
    int mark;
    char * wildcard;
} student;


int highestMark(student[], int, char *);

int main() {
    // Make an array of students
    student all_students[] = {
        {.name = "John", .mark = 75, .wildcard = "Final"},
        {.name = "Mark", .mark = 83, .wildcard = "Q1"},
        {.name = "Melanie", .mark = 81, .wildcard = "Q2"},
        {.name = "Ashley", .mark = 92, .wildcard = "Q3"},
        {.name = "Sandra", .mark = 90, .wildcard = "Final"},
        {.name = "Jacob", .mark = 79, .wildcard = "Q1"},
        {.name = "Marlene", .mark = 74, .wildcard = "Q2"},
        {.name = "Layla", .mark = 70, .wildcard = "Q4"},
        {.name = "John", .mark = 84, .wildcard = "Final"},
        {.name = "Mark", .mark = 83, .wildcard = "Q2"},
        {.name = "Melanie", .mark = 100, .wildcard = "Q2"},
        {.name = "Ashley", .mark = 97, .wildcard = "Q3"},
        {.name = "Aysha", .mark = 100, .wildcard = "Final"},
        {.name = "Devin", .mark = 95, .wildcard = "Q1"},
    };
    // Call the highestMark function for wildcards of value "Final"
    // int arr_length = sizeof(all_students)/sizeof(student);
    int arr_length = sizeof all_students/sizeof all_students[0];
    printf("%d\n", highestMark(all_students, arr_length, "Final"));
}

// Grab the highest mark number given a wildcard
// Wildcards can be Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4 or Final
int highestMark(student students[], int size, char * wildcard) {
    int highest = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < size; i++) {
        if (students[i].wildcard != wildcard) {
            continue;
        }
        if (highest < students[i].mark) {
            highest = students[i].mark;
        }
    }
    return highest;
}
```

I hope this proves useful.

Comment: `sizeof(all_students)/sizeof(student)` is an interesting combination of size of a variable and size of a type.  Consider `sizeof all_students/sizeof all_students[0]` as it is easier to code right, review and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

if Q's are of the same type, then you can pass their offset:

```
struct Student {
    int q1, q2, q3, q4;
};

int highestQ(struct Student students[], int size, size_t offset) {
  for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    struct Student *s = students+i;
    int *q = (int *)(((char *)s) + offset);
    // do something with *q
  }
  return something;
}

// Example of a call
struct Student student_array[10] = { /* whatever to initialize */};
highestQ(student_array, 10, offsetof(struct Student, q2));
```

You may also use an embedded array:

```
struct Student {
    int q[4];
};

int highestQ(struct Student students[], int size, int idx) {
  for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    int q = students[i].q[idx];
    // do what you want with q
  }
  return something;
}

// call example
struct Student student_array[10] = { /* whatever to initialize */};
highestQ(student_array, 10, 2);
```

If Q's are not of the same type or algorithm applied to them may not be the same then similar things have to be applied separately for each case.

Comment: *"if Q's are of the same type"*: it is not needed. `offsetof` will do its job.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes it is required, if not you won't be able to correctly type the dereferencing.

Comment: Where is the issue with `struct S {int a, char b;} s[2] = {{42, '*'}, {42, '*'}}; char c = *((char*)((char*)(&s[1]) + offsetof(s, b))); int i = *((int*)((char*)(&s[1]) + offsetof(s, a)));` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 There is no issue with your code, but OP wants to factorize everything in a single function...I suppose that means same type for every needed member. Isn't it?

Comment: Need one function by type by algorithm. Ok, I understand what you mean.

Comment: @Jarod42 Do you think I need to improve the answer by including your final comment?

Comment: Up to you. but clarification won't hurt ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a more general function to which you pass the `index` of the data member that will be used for the calculation.

For instance, this index can be a `one to one` map to your `Q`. Say, if you pass `1` you consider `Q1` for the calculation, `2` consider `Q2` and so on.

Comment: How would I go about that? I would understand that if each element in the array was an array, but I'm trying to pass an array of structs, and then specify which data member I want to use of each struct in the array.